# @Transactional with timeout is not working in Springboot Application for value other than 1 (timeout=1)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, connection-timeout, query-timeout

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa from Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE, using spring-data-jpa. DB is Oracle. JDK 1.8.

I am using `@Transactional` on top of a method that is calling a long-running query. When the transaction timeout is set to 1, the transaction is timing out within 1 second. When `@Transaction`nis to timeout > 1, there is no timeout exception. The query runs we get the response. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout = 5)
public List<Pojo> doStuff() {
    result = myRepository.findDetails(); -- This call long running native query
  ...
}
```

Strangely, this works when the app is run in debug mode and a breakpoint is kept at the call to repository method. I have tried the following

1. `javax.persistence.query.timeout` with hint also did not timeout
2. `server.connection-timeout=3s` - did not work
3. `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=10` - did not work
4. `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` - works but does not timeout at the specified time.

If 100 is mentioned then it sometimes throws exception in 1 mins sometimes less/more. We are getting response from DB after 5 mins. We would like to timeout before that and send timeout response to the client.

Comment: It may be with a way you are testing `@Transactional`. How are you making sure query takes more than 5 seconds?

Comment: When no timeout is mentioned, the total time is more than 4 mins. That's how we know that it is taking more than 5 seconds.